# "profiling" server side Javascript code on Meteor

Tags: javascript, performance, meteor, server-side

Using WebStorm 2016.1 with Meteor.

Want to be able to “profile” performance of Javascript for Meteor on server.

WebStorm has spy-js which is just what I need ... however have not been able to get it to work with Meteor.
Cannot run 2 instances (Meteor and spy-js) at same time from one instance of WebStorm.
Running each on separate WS instances does not work either.
Start Meteor from terminal ... then Run spy-js from WS ... and then load Meteor prj from within WS (File::OpenURL → localhost:3000) ... has not worked either.

Have looked at Kadira, Chrome DevTools, NodeJS profiling, JS profiling ... but have not seen example of how they could work with server-side JS on Meteor.

I see Kadira has course (BulletProof Meteor) on Nodejs Internals (https://bulletproofmeteor.com/packages) ... but course has been postponed (https://meteorhacks.com/postponing-nodejs-internals-lessons-on-bulletproof-meteor.html).

Best 2 solutions I have found:

1. Make CALL from client to server ... and profile function that does CALL on client side in order to get idea of server performance.
2. Use console.time() and console.timeEnd() functions on server JS code.

I think I am missing something obvious ... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

SUMMARY of what I found ...

Kadira solution → https://kadira.io/platform/kadira-debug/cpu-profiling/taking-a-server-profile

NodeJS solution → https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time

WebStorm duplicate issue posted in 03Nov2014 → see WEB-14065

Comment: Kadira is (was?) a meteor profiling tool. 
The link is now dead. Here is an archive.org backup : https://web.archive.org/web/20170518115842/https://old.kadira.io/platform/kadira-debug/cpu-profiling/taking-a-server-profile